# Каким образом можно программно задать координаты элемента обойдя XML-разметку?

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать произвольной сложности динамический интерфейс. 
Пробовал так:

```
TextView.setLeft(int)
```

не выходит, если элемент находится внутри FrameLayout.

По этой теме нигде не могу найти вразумительного ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Далее у layoutParams вызываешь методы установки margin, например setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

ну а потом

```
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
```

Comment: ошибка: no suitable constructor found for LayoutParams(MainActivity)
Код:
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MainActivity.this);

Comment: `FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MainActivity.this);`
context взял с MainActivity в чем проблема?

Comment: Пардон, согрешил, посмотри изменения в ответе

Comment: Note: MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Что с этим делать? Не обращать внимания?

Comment: Но это практически мой ответ, отличается только сигнатурой конструктора LayoutParams

Comment: FrameLayout.LayoutParams или LayoutParams не важно? мой javac не ругается

Comment: LayoutParams - это класс, инкапсулированный в классах-наслдениках от ViewGroup. Иными словами у любого Layout свой LayoutParams и, если ты в работаешь в Android Studio, то наведя на layoutParams мышкой с зажатым ctrl, ты узнаешь какой именно LayoutParams ты используешь.

Comment: Зачем они нужны разные? Дело в том, что если твой TextView расположен внутри LinearLayout, то к нему можно будет применить только LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Код скомплируется при любом LayoutParams, но при выполнении упадет, если ты применишь не тот, что нужен

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(100,100,0,0);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv1.setTextSize(80);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    tv1.setText("text1");

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM));
    tv2.setTextSize(50);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv2.setText("text2");

FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    fl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    fl.addView(tv1);
    fl.addView(tv2);
    setContentView(fl);
  }
}
```

Ура! Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, комбинация:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.setMargins(100,100,0,0);
```

РАБОТАЕТ!